# how to access nested json using vue.js in this example?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

How would I correctly access the nested json for stage.name in the example below?

You can see in the template I am trying to access stage name.

vue.js

```
created() {
    url="http://{{ api_endpoint }}"
    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(body => {
            for(i=0; i<body.length; i++){
                this.job_execs.push({
                    'name': JSON.stringify(body[i].job.name),
                    'build_id': JSON.stringify(body[i].build_num),
                    'env': JSON.stringify(body[i].job.env),
                })
            }
    })



template: `
      <li v-for="item in this.job_execs">
        [[ item.build_num ]]
        <li v-if="stage in item.job">
          [[ stage.name ]]
        </li>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

example api

```
[
    {
        "build_num": 12,
        "job": {
            "name": "test-job",
            "env": "DEV",
            "tool": {
                "env": "DEV",
            },
            "product": {
                "name": "vuejs"
            },
            "platform": {
                "name": "none"
            },
            "stage": [
                {
                    "name": "stage1"
                },
                {
                    "name": "stage2"
                },
                {
                    "name": "stage3"
                },
            ]
        },
]
```

I am guessing I need to create a new list in the created hook and start pushing the stage names?  But then I will have two lists?  Not sure what is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create an `<li>` for each stage it would be:

```html
<li v-for="stage in item.job.stage">
  [[ stage.name ]]
</li>
```

Note `v-for`, not `v-if`.

You can think of `v-for` as being the template equivalent of this:

```js
item.job.stage.forEach(stage => {
    // ...
})
```

If you just want the first one then it's:

```html
<li>
  [[ item.job.stage[0].name ]]
</li>
```

If you did want to pursue the idea of creating a second list then you should do it using a computed property, no need to do anything in a `created` hook. In that computed property you could reduce down your data into a format that is easier to work with in your template. I'm not sure that's warranted in this case but if your needs are more complex than the example code you've posted then that might be a good way to go rather than writing a convoluted template.

**Update:**

So in full this would be:

```html
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in job_execs">
    [[ item.build_num ]]
    <ul>
      <li v-for="stage in item.job.stage">
        [[ stage.name ]]
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In your JavaScript code there's no need for all that `JSON.stringify` stuff.

```js
fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(body => {
        this.job_execs = body
    })
```

If you want something a bit closer to your original code with `build_num` renamed to `build_id` then there are several options, such as:

```js
fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(body => {
        for (let i = 0; i < body.length; i++) {
            this.job_execs.push({
                build_id: body[i].build_num,
                job: body[i].job
            })
        }
    })
```

You'd then need to refer to `build_num` as `build_id` in your template.

Personally I'd be more inclined to use `forEach`, `for`/`of` or `map` instead of a straight `for` loop. e.g.:

```js
fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(body => {
        this.job_execs = body.map(item => {
            return {
                build_id: item.build_num,
                job: item.job
            }
        })
    })
```

All of this is only necessary if you really need to transform the format of the data though. Otherwise just stick to `this.job_execs = body`.

Comment: In this example - what if the number of stages for a given job is unknown?  I want to list all the job stages but the number of job stages will be different based on the job

Comment: @david I believe that's what my first example does. It uses `v-for` to iterate over the array `item.job.stage`.

Comment: oh - did not even notice that.  Thanks!

Comment: Two things: I think you mean `{{ stage.name }}` and not `[[ stage.name ]]`, and you'll need to nest the second layer of `li`s inside of a `ul` or `ol`.

Comment: @DavidWeldon The question used `[[ stage.name ]]` so I followed suit. I assume he is either using an alternative templating engine or has set the `delimiters` option in Vue. https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters

Comment: Nice - I didn't know you could set the delimiters. :)

Comment: Yea I set the delimiters to use brackets

Comment: I dont think this will solution will work with my example because if you look at the template in the OP, I am trying to access item.build_num as well as stage.  I think with your solution there is only a list of stages.  Any ideas?

Comment: @david Your code should contain two loops. The outer loop remains exactly the same as you had it in the question. It is the outer loop that introduces the identifier `item` and you can use it to access `item.build_num` just as you did originally. My code only shows the inner loop. The inner loop also relies on `item` existing to access `item.job.stage`, so it would be meaningless without the outer loop.

Comment: any chance you can update answer? - i'm having trouble following